# Dash_extensions doesn't find Namespace after beeing built with cx_freeze

Tags: python, plotly-dash, cx-freeze

I use the dash_extensions.javascript function `Namespace` to use js code in my dash application.
It works fine when running in the IDE. After building with cx_freeze the Namespace is not found.
The exact error is:

> `No match for [myNamespace.mySubNamespace.function_name] in the global window object.`

Similar errors occure when using the `assign` function of dash_extensions and when using dash_transcrypt `module_to_props()`

I am using:

- `dash=2.1.0`
- `dash_extensions=0.0.67`
- `dash_transcrypt=0.0.6`
- `dash_leaflet=0.1.18`
- `cx_freeze=6.10`

Can someone reproduce this behavior? Is this intentional or is my use case not suited for dash?

Answer (score 0):

Try to place inside yout Dash `/assets` folder a .js file with all your functions (e.g. `dashExtensions.js`)

Example:

```js
window.dashExtensions = Object.assign({}, window.dashExtensions, {
  default: {
    drawMarkers: function (feature, latlng, context) {
      return L.circleMarker(latlng, { radius: 2 }); // sender a simple circle marker.
    },
  },
});
```

Then inside your python code put `ns = Namespace("dashExtensions", "default")`.
Notice the correspondance between the **dashExtensions** and the **default**